# HK2 Custom InterceptionService to intercept REST endpoints not working

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have below sample jersey application, where i have used HK2 to intercept rest endpoints having custom annotations to validate header.
But it seems REST endpoint is never getting intercepted

While debugging i could see the endpoint class is not scanned by MyInterceptionService class.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public  @interface CustomInterceptor {
}

@Path("/")
public class RestEndpoint{

    @GET
    @Path("intercepted")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @ManagedAsync
    @CustomInterceptor
    public String getIntercepted() {
        return "ServerResource: Intercepted method invoked\n";
    }
}


@ApplicationPath("/")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {
 public Application() {
        packages("com.example");
        register(new MyInterceptionBinder());
    }
}

public class MyInterceptionBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MyInterceptionService.class)
                .to(org.glassfish.hk2.api.InterceptionService.class)
                .in(Singleton.class);
    }
}


public class MyInterceptionService implements InterceptionService {
    private final List<MethodInterceptor> interceptors = Collections.singletonList(new MyInterceptor());

    @Override
    public Filter getDescriptorFilter() {
       return BuilderHelper.allFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public List<MethodInterceptor> getMethodInterceptors(Method method) {
        System.err.println("----"+method.getDeclaringClass());
        if(method.isAnnotationPresent(CustomInterceptor.class)) {
            return interceptors;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<ConstructorInterceptor> getConstructorInterceptors(Constructor<?> constructor) {
        return null;
    }
}



public class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable { 
        return invocation.proceed();
    }
}
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Doesn't @CustomInterceptor need to go on the RestEndpoint class, not the method?  Just a guess

Comment: I want to intercept only certain methods in Class. So added it in method level. Made the functionality work by https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html but HK2   injection didn't work.